# java server faces in Eclipse 3.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Is it possible to write a java server faces application in eclipse 3.2.0 ?

I am asking this because eclipse 3.2.0 is not allowing me to add tomcat 6 as a server.

is it that java server faces do not work on tomcat 5.5 ??

Comment: May I ask you what blocked you from using the latest Eclipse?

Comment: I am using galileo as well but this is a question out of curiosity dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 2007, [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-jsf-dev/msg00261.html) already reported the problem:

> First thing is Eclipse 3.2.2 does not support Java EE5. So can't develop any java EE 5 project.

And since one key concern of the Java EE 5 specification has been the alignment of its webtier technologies, namely JavaServer Pages (JSP), JavaServer Faces (JSF), and JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL), you may have a hard time running your JSF page in an 3.2 eclipse.

The outcome of this alignment effort has been the Unified Expression Language (EL), which integrates the expression languages defined by JSP 2.0 and JSF 1.1.

So if you are using EL, you really need to upgrade eclipse to have the right server level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop a JavaServer Faces application in Eclipse 3.2.  You just need to bring in the jars in the war yourself.  That's what I did.